# Swap first paragraph of content to be the last one

Tags: php, mysql, text, phpmyadmin

When i run

```
SELECT * FROM `content` where article_id=123
```

I get result

```
<p>{sometag}some things{/sometag}</p>
<p>some content</p>
<p>some more content</p>
```

I need to do modification of that result in order to get:

```
<p>some content</p>
<p>some more content</p>
<p>{sometag}some things{/sometag}</p>
```

Note: that first paragraph is moved to the end.

I have to do that over `phpMyAdmin`, but I can also use PHP. In PHP i know how to conenct to database, load and update content, but i dont know how to switch paragraph? Need help on that.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Loading results, doing some basic edits on them, and saving all of that.

Comment: Storing HTML tags in the database is a very bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m forced to make a lot of assumptions here as you haven’t really written a question or even provided any information.

You say “content of a column” so I will assume you have those 3 HTML paragraph tags stored in a column of a database somewhere and you want to change the order they are returned.

The order you want isn't alphabetic so you can’t order them by the stored values. You should create a new column and order that, for example create a column named “manual_order” and then:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY manual_order
```

**Edit**

Your update to your post makes it clear what you're trying to do - it's always easier when 'you' know what you mean but not always clear to everyone else!

The order of the results returned from MySQL cannot be relied upon unless you are supplying an ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

Will return then in insert order providing you haven't had any DELETE / UPDATE or REPLACE to that table.

If you're doing SELECT * FROM table with an INNODB table they will be returned by PRIMARY KEY order and not INSERT order.

If you want to change the order you must supply an ORDER BY clause.  If you want an order that doesn't make sense in numeric terms then as suggested it would be best to create another column where you can specify the order and use that in the ORDER BY clause.

If you're using INNODB and wanting a reverse of what has been queried you could just use:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY primarykey DESC
```

Comment: Huh, i thought i was clear. Anyway my post has been updated. Thanks!

Comment: @RhymeGuy your edit makes what you're doing clear now :-) I will add an edit to my answer